# Accessibility Event occurs only once after enabling the Accessibility Service

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I've just started coding my app which uses Accessibility Service. I'll explain my problem in detail.

Below is my `onServiceConnected` method of `MyAccessibilityService` class

```
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = getServiceInfo();
    info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED | AccessibilityEvent.WINDOWS_CHANGE_ADDED;

    info.packageNames = new String[]
            {THIRD_PARTY_APP_PACKAGE};

    info.notificationTimeout = 100;
    this.setServiceInfo(info);
}
```

The app is detecting events in `onAccessibilityEvent()` method

```
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
    if (source == null) {
        return;
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "Event Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now when I open the third party app, I'm getting the Toast "Event occured". Now I close the app and when I open it again, the method is not called and I don't get any Toast. To make it working again, I have to disable the accessibility service of my app in my phone's Settings and again enable it.

I know I'm missing something and my only question is what should be the additional part of code or what modifications I need in order to detect the event every time I open the third party app?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting rid of the notification timeout? You probably don't need it, and it isn't the best-tested API.